# Docker API to automate pull and run

Tags: go, docker

I want to integrate my Go code with Docker which is also in Go. I want to do something like:

```
myapp.Run()
IMG := dockerapi.Pull("namespace/my image")
IMG.Run()
```

What do you recommend if I want to run docker commands in the middle of my Go program program flow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker offers a rest based [API](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.14/) for interacting with it programatically:

Example request:

```
POST /images/create?fromImage=base HTTP/1.1
```

Example response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{"status":"Pulling..."}
{"status":"Pulling", "progress":"1 B/ 100 B", "progressDetail":{"current":1, "total":100}}
{"error":"Invalid..."}
...
```

there is a [wrapper](https://github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient) written in go here, though I have not used it myself.